# Configure Client Certificate Mapping Authentication with Active Directory

Tags: authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, iis-8.5

I want to implement "Client Certificate Mapping Authentication with Active Directory" to provide enterprise security to our planned API.

- I just added a Client Certificate to my test user in the Active Directory.
- Installed the Client Certificate to my client
- Then I installed the Server feature "Client Certificate Mapping Authentication" (**NOT** IIS).
- Afterwards I enabled the feature in IIS at Server-level under authentication.
- Then a set SSL as required and disabled anonymous authentication.

Sadly its not working :(
I can choose my Client Certificate from a list when opening the API but then I get 401.2. Wireshark shows that the Client and the Server are having a handshake but the Server never asks our DC directly or via LDAP for the user of some kind.

What did I have do wrong?

I also tried the request from a Client in the same subnet and without the proxy to avoid firewall and/or proxy issues...

In general SSL is working: When I enable anonymous auth the API is working.

Kind Regards